# Two-proportion z test: is it best for my problem, and can I pool data from multiple "replicate" populations?

Tags: proportion, z-test, pooling

I am examining populations (cultures) of yeast cells and scoring them for a particular trait.  The data is categorical; within a population, a yeast cell either has the trait or it does not.  I wish to compare two populations -- two genetically different strains of yeast --  to see whether there are differences in the proportion of of cells with the trait.

**First question:**  would a two-proportion z test be the way to go here?

**Second question:**  If so, in all of the examples I’ve seen the samples are taken from one “replicate” of each population.  Working with yeast, I can set up multiple independent populations (cultures) for each particular strain (in my experiment I sampled four independent cultures for each of the two strains I examined -- scoring several million cells in each sample).  Obviously in humans or many other populations such “replicates” are not possible.  But for me they are.  **So my question is this:**  **do you think it is valid to pool the data from all four replicates of each population?**  Or would it be best to show the calculation from one “representative” population for each?

I am not a statistician nor do I have good tools beyond Excel to do these calculations, so I am looking for a robust yet manageable approach to analyze my data.  I can handle a Z test if that is the way to go, but if it's not a valid approach I would love to hear alternatives!

Thank you in advance!